# Button BackColor (seems to) ignore alpha channel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I built a little Tic-Tac-Toe game in winforms using nothing but layout panels, buttons and labels. Each game has 2 players, and each player is associated with a mark and color. When a player claims a field (clicks a button on a grid), that button's `BackColor` is changed to that player's color.

What I'd like to do now is have the open fields in the grid become a semi-transparent shade of a player's color while the cursor is over a field.

For some reason, this isn't working for my buttons:

```
Public Class FieldButton
    Inherits Button

    ' ... Omitting for brevity '


    Private _mouseIn As Boolean

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
        _mouseIn = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
        _mouseIn = False
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property BackColor As Color
        Get
            If Field.HasOwner Then
                Return Field.Owner.Color
            ElseIf _mouseIn Then
                Return Color.FromArgb(16, Presenter.Game.CurrentPlayer.Color)
            End If
            Return MyBase.BackColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            MyBase.BackColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared ReadOnly FullPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 3)
    Private Shared ReadOnly SemiTransparentPen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(64, Color.Black), 3)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(pevent As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(pevent)
        If Field.HasOwner Then
            PaintMark(pevent.Graphics, pevent.ClipRectangle, Field.Owner.Mark, FullPen)
        ElseIf _mouseIn And Not Presenter.Game.IsGameOver Then
            PaintMark(pevent.Graphics, pevent.ClipRectangle, Presenter.Game.CurrentPlayer.Mark, SemiTransparentPen)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' ... '

End Class
```

In the above code, `Field` is another object that represents a field in the grid. Each field has an `Owner`, which is set to the player that claimed the field (or null).

Anyway, the line that is supposed to do the magic:

```
Return Color.FromArgb(16, Presenter.Game.CurrentPlayer.Color)
```

Has the following result:

[image]

It might be a little difficult to see due to the illusion created by the semi-transparent mark, but the button background color `FromArgb(16, ...)` is **exactly** the same as the buttons with alpha channel 255.

What am I not doing right?

**EDIT**

Turns out that the button's `FlatButtonAppearance.MouseOverBackColor` property takes precedence over the button's `BackColor` when  `FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat`.

I don't think that explains why my button was still showing purple on mouse-over. I'm guessing that `MouseOverBackColor` defaults to the current backcolor, but ignores the alpha channel.

Comment: This looks like some form of .net, from memory .net used to have an opacity property on form objects. Try looking for and changing that.

Comment: Sorry... what? Oh. No, `Button` doesn't have an opacity property.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: VB.NET, but should be the same for C#.

Comment: Code markup seems to be acting up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Research says this should work for you, add it to your buttons constructor;

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I added that line and it made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Try checking that you follow this guide, otherwise I don't have much of a clue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well it does seem to respect `Color.Transparent`, but I still don't know how to set a "full" color with a decreased opacity.

Comment: That guide says it should be possible using a combination of that and ARGB colours.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. It doesn't work for `Color.Transparent`. I suspect that it may be using the base implementation to pain the background, since I'm not actually changing `BackColor` on the base class.

Comment: I figured it out, but you would've never guessed it. The trick was to comment out `MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)`. Something in there was painting the backcolor without respecting the transparency setting.